# how to troubleshoot the error of Job Failed in Gitlab after running the pipline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

**Pipline created**

```
stages:
    - test
postman_test:
    stage: test
    image: postman/newman_alpine33
    script:
        - newman --version
```

**The Response Received**

> Running with gitlab-runner 13.5.0-rc2 (71c90c86)   on
> docker-auto-scale 72989761 Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
> 00:18 Using Docker executor with image postman/newman_alpine33 ...
> Pulling docker image postman/newman_alpine33 ... Using docker image
> sha256:5cf77cf6f69fea69952c84d804c6dee67bc7c2b66d2962769dfb99ebbd69dedb
> for postman/newman_alpine33 with digest
> postman/newman_alpine33@sha256:7cd459dc2e9dd8a743548c4f8080f2c38c4e7b7163a0d533ecc3c8099b93b6d9
> ... Preparing environment 00:04 Running on
> runner-72989761-project-21805329-concurrent-0 via
> runner-72989761-srm-1602779557-742dd19f... Getting source from Git
> repository 00:01 $ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT" Fetching changes with
> git depth set to 50... Initialized empty Git repository in
> /builds/aylin2/project-test/.git/ Created fresh repository. Checking
> out fb728cf0 as master... Skipping Git submodules setup Executing
> "step_script" stage of the job script 00:02 error: unknown option '-c'
> Cleaning up file based variables 00:00 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1